# Vagrant VirtualBox (Ubuntu Trusty) stops responding after several days

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, supervisord

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64) using Vagrant [vagrant:amd64 1:1.6.3] (VirtualBox). My host system is the same OS version.

After several days of flawless (or so it seems) operation, the vagrant box will stop responding... or more specifically:

1. My Supervisor managed services no longer respond (webserver etc...).
2. I **can** `vagrant ssh` into the box and navigate around most directories
3. Anything interacting with the shared `/vagrant` directory will not respond (including `sudo supervisorctl`).
4. Running `vagrant halt` from the host machine will fail to halt peacefully and will eventually forcefully be halted.
5. Re-upping the box afterwards will then give several more happy days.

The only thing that I can see (that might be of relevance) in `/var/log/syslog` is the following:

```
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.711678] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000006c0000003f
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714065] IP: [<ffffffffa00a10f6>] vbglPhysHeapExcludeBlock+0x16/0x60 [vboxguest]
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] PGD 3c7c7067 PUD 0
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] Modules linked in: rpcsec_gss_krb5 nfsv4 vboxsf(OF) nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl nfs lockd sunrpc fscache dm_crypt ppdev serio_raw parport_pc vboxguest(OF) parport ahci psmouse libahci e1000
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] CPU: 0 PID: 1632 Comm: vminfo Tainted: GF          O 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] task: ffff88003c202fe0 ti: ffff88003cd20000 task.ti: ffff88003cd20000
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa00a10f6>]  [<ffffffffa00a10f6>] vbglPhysHeapExcludeBlock+0x16/0x60 [vboxguest]
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] RSP: 0018:ffff88003cd21d78  EFLAGS: 00010206
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] RAX: 0000006c00000027 RBX: ffff88003ce5014c RCX: ffff88003ce60000
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] RDX: ffff88003ce50124 RSI: ffff88003ce50124 RDI: ffff88003ce5016c
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] RBP: ffff88003cd21d78 R08: 0000000000000292 R09: ffff88003ce5014c
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] R10: ffff88003c6fcc10 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: ffff88003ce50124
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] R13: ffff88003ce5014c R14: 0000000000000020 R15: 0000000000000000
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] FS:  00007fc8b5475700(0000) GS:ffff88003fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] CR2: 0000006c0000003f CR3: 000000003ccf0000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] Stack:
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  ffff88003cd21d98 ffffffffa00a1609 ffff88003ce5014c ffff88003cd21e70
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  ffff88003cd21db0 ffffffffa009faae ffff88003cd21e78 ffff88003cd21e38
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  ffffffffa009de5e ffff880000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000050
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] Call Trace:
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffffa00a1609>] VbglPhysHeapFree+0xc9/0xe0 [vboxguest]
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffffa009faae>] VbglGRFree+0x1e/0x30 [vboxguest]
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffffa009de5e>] VBoxGuestCommonIOCtl+0x54e/0x1b90 [vboxguest]
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffff811a103b>] ? kfree+0xab/0x140
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffffa009b7ce>] vboxguestLinuxIOCtl+0x9e/0x200 [vboxguest]
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffff8101b7e9>] ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffff8109d1ad>] ? sched_clock_local+0x1d/0x80
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffff811cfd10>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x2e0/0x4c0
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffff8109ddf4>] ? vtime_account_user+0x54/0x60
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffff811cff71>] SyS_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  [<ffffffff8172c87f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] Code: 05 00 00 c7 05 c8 05 02 00 00 00 00 00 5d c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 66 66 66 90 48 8b 47 10 55 48 89 e5 48 85 c0 74 0c 48 8b 57 18 <48> 89 50 18 488 8b 47 10 48 8b 57 18 48 85 d2 74 19 48 89 42 10
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] RIP  [<ffffffffa00a10f6>] vbglPhysHeapExcludeBlock+0x16/0x60 [vboxguest]
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663]  RSP <ffff88003cd21d78>
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.714663] CR2: 0000006c0000003f
Aug 20 22:45:31 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [226490.828096] ---[ end trace 1eefe230ded2b9f8 ]---
```

Happy to supply any more information that people request that I've missed out.

Comment: I think you might hitting some VirtualBox bug here.
See similar report [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11610).
Have you tried using other Vagrant box as well?

Comment: I have been unable to find a way around this and as such have moved away from the Vagrant VirtualBox setup to a VMware virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://www.vagrantbox.es/ then you will notice that virtualbox guest additions isn't included in the VM, which is the cause for some of the problems you are having.

You might be able to install Virtualbox Guest Additions using Puppet or what ever provisioning option you choose. I imagine you will have to manually setup the /vagrant shared folder.